# error : Matrix must have equal dimensions

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, knn

I have been trying this. Model can't give me confusion matrix

```
    fit <- rpart(taste ~ ., data = train,method="class",control = rpart.control(cp = 0.01)) 
    summary(fit)



    knn_prediction <- predict(fit, test)
    confusionMatrix(knn_prediction, test$taste)
```

#when i tried the confusion matrix it gives me error : matrix must have equal dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default argument of `type` of `predict.raprt` is `prob`, which makes `knn_prediction` of yours matrix.

You should use `type = "class"` to make confusion matrix with your code.

Try

```
knn_prediction <- predict(fit, test, type = "class")
```